# Label ECDF plot points

Tags: r, plot, cdf, ecdf

I'm trying to label the points of an ECDF plot with another column from my data field.
Currently I'm using this:

```
untouched = read.table("results-untouched.tsv", sep="\t")
plot.ecdf(untouched$V4, xlim=c(0.75,1.25), ylim=c(0,1), col='green', verticals=T)
```

which plots allright, but I'm then unable to add the labels to the points. The labels would be in `untouched$V1`.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add labels, you can use the `text` function. For example, we generate some data

```
x = sort(rnorm(10))
```

then create the ecdf object (`plot.ecdf` does this automatically),

```
m = ecdf(x)
```

and plot `m`

```
plot(m)
```

To add labels, we use the `text` function. The x coordinates are the data, the y coordinates are the output from the `ecdf` function (with an additional 0.03 to avoid over-plotting):

```
text(x, m(x) + 0.03, LETTERS[1:10])
```